# php filter strings before and after specific word with varied lengths

Tags: php

I have a string similar to this....

```
$string = "order apples oranges pears and bananas from username";
```

How can I get it into something like this?

```
$products = "apples oranges pears and bananas";
$username = "username";
```

Comment: will the "$string" always be the same number of elements, or will it change? the order of the items will stay the same?

Comment: You're writing your own query parsing engine?

Comment: have you tried regular expressions?

Comment: @Silvertiger the length will always be different.

Comment: @Brad The reason I need to do this is because im receiving many different "commands" via sms and need to test each command but im struggling with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "order apples oranges pears and bananas from username";
list($products,$username) = explode(" from ", $string);
$products = str_replace('order ', '', $products);


//print results for verification
var_dump(array($products,$username));
```

outputs:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(32) "apples oranges pears and bananas" [1]=> string(8) "username" }
```

but this will not handle different "commands" other than "order" and also assumes all whitespace between words is a single space character.  You need more complex code to handle multiple cases, but that would require more information from you.

Comment: This is better because it removes the "order" Thanks

Comment: @codercake gave a great answer. Check this one also (fixed) just to help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8860540/410273

Answer (score 3):

```
list($products,$username) = explode("from", $string);
```

Comment: Why didnt I think of that, Its so simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = "order apples oranges pears and bananas from username";

$part = explode("order",$string);

$order = explode("from",$part[1]);

echo $order[0];

echo $order[1];

?>
```

Check here live demo http://codepad.org/5iD02e6b

Answer (score 0):

answer has already been accepted, but still.. my answer has the advantage that if there are errors in the original string, the resulting variables will be empty. which is good because then it's easy to test if everything went according to plan :)

```
<?php
    $string = "order apples oranges pears and bananas from username";
    $products_regex = "/^order\\s(.*)\\sfrom/i";
    $username_regex = "/from\\s(.*)$/i";
    $products_matches = array();
    $username_matches = array();
    preg_match($products_regex, $string, $products_matches);
    preg_match($username_regex, $string, $username_matches);
    $products = "";
    $username = "";

    if(count($products_matches) === 2 &&
            count($username_matches) === 2)
    {
        $products = $products_matches[1];
        $username = $username_matches[1];
    }

    echo "products: '$products'<br />\nuser name: '$username'";
```